# Network problems in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, server, system-installation, desktop-environments

I have installed server 19.10 and the did the following:

- `sudo apt update`
- `sudo apt upgrade`
- Then I did a reboot
- I then did

  `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`

All seems to go well

- Then I confirmed that there were no additional updates...
- Then I did a reboot

The system came up well.. and all seems to be great...

But..  Things like the settings option can not see the network and the software program to download programs can not see the network and suggests me look at the network setting..

The network interface is now seen with `ip a`  and is no longer eth0 but follows a new standard...

Is there a new updated ubuntu-desktop package to install???

To save the question .. why install the server and then the desktop when the desktop version of ubuntu 19.10 works great!!  I am planning to install UBUNTU 19.10 on my Raspberry PI 4 and want the desktop experience...  I am testing the install on my faster PC..

Any insight would be helpful

Further to questions:
- `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml`

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      match:
        name: enp0s3
      set-name: eth0
      dhcp4: yes
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        enp0s3:
            dhcp4: true
    version: 2
```

- `sudo lshw -class network`

```
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: enp0s3
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:e1:30:c6
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.1.54 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:19 memory:f8200000-f821ffff ioport:d020(size=8)
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Why did you install the server version when it sounds like you wanted the desktop version? In the server version, you have to edit `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file to make the network work.

Comment: There is only a server version for the install on the Raspberry PI 4.  So I plan to install the server version and then add the desktop to let me use the GUI experience

Comment: I have tried to edit the .yaml file..   I am having problems setting the logical name of the ethernet device as eth0 as it used to be...

Comment: Ok, edit your question and show me `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and `sudo lshw -C network`.

Comment: I figured out how to add the answers into the original question.. It is more readable

Comment: I tried option to disable the cloud-init network.. and then rebooted..  Surprisingly things are working better..  I even get the network symbol on the status bar.  I deleted the 99-disable-network.. file and rebooted and all is still working..Odd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your .yaml file is wrong, because you mix NetworkManager and networkd syntax.

The following two .yaml files are for a pure server installation... no Desktop, no GUI.

**Your .yaml file should look like this...**

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    enp0s3:
      dhcp4: true
```

---

**And if you REALLY want to use eth0:**

`sudo pico /etc/default/grub` or `sudo -H gedit /etc/default/grub`

Search for "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash net.ifnames=0"

`sudo update-grub`

And then use this .yaml...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
```

---

**Then...**

`sudo netplan --debug generate`

`sudo netplan apply`

`reboot`

---

**Update #1:**

If you decide to use NetworkManager, and the GUI to setup your network, then you need this .yaml...

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Remember to always use the `sudo netplan...` commands that I gave earlier.

Comment: I saw the comment to disable cloud-init in the original post..I did as it suggested.  I rebooted and the network symbol appeared and all the utilities can work with the network... I removed the disable and rebooted.. network symbol stayed. I tried your first .yaml file and applied it and the network symbol went away.  put my original .yaml file and the symbol came back..  I agree going back to the eth0 is a poor choice as it eventually will disapear.  I wonder if the desktop utilities need the render to be NetworkManager?

Comment: @fredflintston Please see Update #1 in my answer.

Comment: @fredflintston Edit your question and show me `ls -al /etc/systemd/network`.

Comment: Just to be really sure...  I am going to start from scratch with the server.. then the desktop.. then doing the netplan and see without disabling cloud-init...  Looking good..  and thanks to you learning a lot..  (thanks)

Comment: @fredflintston  I saw your comments that were an edit to my answer. It sounds like my Update #1 solved your problem. Please don't edit my answer, but rather, place them as comments, fair enough? Accept the answer if it made a difference. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry.. just learning!!!  I just completed a full server install.. then the desktop.. then the netplan configuration and after a reboot... all worked as wanted!!!..  Thank you so much for your help and patience..  (one note.. there is a lot of information out there.. about editing grub files and defeating the netplan approach..  This simple netplan approach is very nice and simple (you need to read about the commands ip, and netplan. and to know to edit the .yaml file with the `sudo gedit /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml`

Comment: I just tried to do the up-arrow.. and because I am a newbie.. my vote counts.. but does not show...  The check mark went green...

Comment: @fredflintston Glad it all worked out for you. To learn more, see https://netplan.io/examples. Also, when using `sudo gedit` you should always use `sudo -H gedit...`.

Comment: Thank you for all your help ..  and guidance!